# eclipse-maven project - NoClassDefFoundError running from eclipse but runs fine from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, pom.xml

I am having issues runtime-resolving a jar file.

I used maven install:install and imported the jar file into my local maven repository.
Then included this jar file in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.adsafe</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So, the project compiles fine.  (FYI..its a maven enabled eclipse project).  but when i run the project i get a NoClassDefFound error for one of the classes inside this jar.

My packaging is 'war', so i assume this jar has to be put into the WEB-INF/lib folder along with the other jars, so it has to be there in the class path.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Where am i going wrong?

Thanks for any help!

FYI...
I am using eclipse, m2eclipse (maven plugin), and running this from within eclipse.

Comment: Does the WEB-INF/lib folder of your Eclipse deployment contain this jar (or for that matter jars of other dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it from the commandline? What also might help is cleaning your project in eclipse.

Comment: works fine in command line! looks like there is a problem running it from eclipse. I tried cleaning the project, did Maven->Update Dependencies, but no use.  Any other thing that needs to be done for eclipse?